# CoreData migration - delete rules of relationships

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-data, migration

I've found nothing about `migration rules` in case of changing the `deletion rule` of a `managedObjects relationship`

My initial coredata model contained an entity with a relationship. The delete rule of this relationship was `cascade`. I had to change this behavior to `Nullify`.

Therefore I've created a `new version of my coredata model` but without any lightweight migration and it still works. So I wounder if I should have done adding a new version of my model or if the changing the deletion rules (e.g. from `cascade` to `nullify`) doesn't effect/need any migration.

Any suggestions?

Comment: No lightweight migration? So you don't use `NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption` or `NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption` when adding the persistent store?

Comment: No I am using the following to create my store: coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType 
                                   configuration:nil 
                                             URL:storeURL 
                                         options:nil 
                                           error:&error]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Deletion rules specify the behavior of Core Data *at runtime*: If one object is deleted, other relationships may be set to NULL, or related objects may be deleted as well.

Therefore I assumed that the deletion rules are stored only in the Core Data model, but not in the persistent store file.

To verify this, I have created 2 store files from 2 Core Data models with identical entities, but different deletion rules. The `NSStoreModelVersionHashes` in the persistent stores `metadata` dictionary were identical.

In fact, both SQLite files were identical with the only exception of the "Z_UUID" in the "Z_METADATA" table, which is the `NSStoreUUID` of the persistent store file.

Also, `addPersistentStoreWithType:...` would fail if the version hashes of the loaded store are different from the hashes in the model.

Changing the deletion rules should therefore not be a problem.

Comment: That's exactly what I experienced - identical hashes. I was just woundering, because in the apple doc I found that the deleteRules should be relevant though: [...] For each property in each entity, the following attributes must be equal: name, isOptional, isTransient,
isReadOnly, for attributes attributeType, and for relationships destinationEntity, minCount,
maxCount, deleteRule, and inverseRelationship [...]! So wouldn't you neither create a new version for the change? I am not seeing any advantage of a new one...

Comment: @Alexander: I must admit that I did not look up the documentation (can you give me the location?), I just tested it as described. And you have tested that `addPersistentStoreWithType:` works, so I do not see a problem.

Comment: Here u go (Page 8 at the bottom): https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation//Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/CoreDataVersioning.pdf

Comment: @Alexander: I would assume that the Versioning+Migration guide is wrong at that point. If you look up `versionHash` in the `NSRelationshipDescription` documentation: There they mention destination entity, inverse relationship, min + max count, *but not* the delete rule.

Comment: I think so, too. Anyway, now we now it doesn't affect versioning. Great thanks for your effort!